# Parsing error:Unterminated JSX contents (Fatal)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Can someone help in this parsing error, I have close the View tag but still it throws an error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';
import Albumlist from './src/components/Albumlist';

const App = () => (

<View>    
    <Header headerText={'Albums'} />
    <Albumlist /> 
</View> //The error is displayed in this line of the code!
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

Comment: It might very well be caused by one of the components being referenced not being properly terminated, which results in the whole thing not being terminated.

Comment: The components individually work well ,but when parse it under the View tab it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

use this
import {Header} from './src/components/header';
instead of
import Header from './src/components/header';

Comment: That is not the problem I guess. Anyways,it still didn't work